# Initialising a function pointer inside a struct

Tags: rust

I've a struct that contains a function pointer

```
struct A {
    b: fn() -> bool,
}

fn main() {
    fn x() -> bool {
        true
    }
    let a = A { b: x };
    println!("{}", (a.b)())
}
```

The above snippet compiles and works as expected. Now, I am trying to avoid the defining the function seperately and do it inline in `struct` definition. Something like this,

```
struct A{
    b: fn() -> bool
}

fn main(){
    let a = A { b: fn x() -> bool { true } };
    println!("{}", (a.b)())
}
```

The above code doesn't compile.

Of course, it works with closures

```
struct A {
    b: fn() -> bool,
}

fn main() {
    let a = A { b: || true };
    println!("{}", (a.b)())
}
```

**Question 1)** Is there a way for me to assign function directly to a struct field without defining it seperately(inline).

**Question 2)** Functions are similar to Closures. If there are no captures, they are identical for all [practical purposes](https://ricardomartins.cc/2015/10/12/practical_differences_between_rust_closures_and_functions). Is it safe/optimal to do this (define closures instead of functions) for  struct initialisations?

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=da29c34931e0c78f99bd1ac8ab9ba947&version=stable)

Comment: [**One** question per question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Question 1)** Is there a way for me to assign function directly to a struct field without defining it separately (inline).

No.

Functions are items, items need be defined separately from their usage.

> **Question 2)** Functions are similar to Closures. If there are no captures, they are identical for all practical purposes. Is it safe/optimal to do this (define closures instead of functions) for struct initialization?

Yes.

I would even go so far as to say that this is the idiomatic way of using closures: you rarely need to assign them a name before using them.

And if your closure accidentally captures, then it cannot be implicitly transformed into a `fn` and the compiler will error out.